# Understanding context in .Net Task execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task, synchronizationcontext

I have been trying to understand the concept of context in Task execution in .Net. However, I still am unable to relate `context` to basic concept of OS threads. While going through [this blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), I sort of got the following idea of what a context is:

> In GUI applications, there is a single GUI thread which has all the
>   GUI elements. Now, because one needs to come in the GUI thread to
>   access the GUI elements, I am assuming the GUI thread has the GUI
>   elements initialized in its stack space which it doesn't share with
>   other threads. Therefore, the `awaitable` needs to schedule the
>   remainder of the function in the GUI thread if the remainder function
>   wants to access some GUI element. Similarly, if we talk about HTTP
>   application which accept HTTP get/post requests, there is a thread
>   which gets spawned when a request arrives. This thread contains the request context like IP address of the user. Now, if the remainder
>   function wants to access some HTTP context properties, it has to execute in that thread.

While reading [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/), I came across the idea of `context being copied`. This has led to me believe the following:

> The context of a thread is data members like IP address, GUI elements
>   etc. When the remainder of a function is scheduled after an awaitable
>   completes, the remainder may need the context to be present, but not
>   necessarily on the same thread. So, what is done is any thread is
>   taken out of the thread pool and the context is copied onto that
>   thread so that it is accessible. Thereafter, the remainder function is
>   scheduled on this thread. This can cause a deadlock in the following way. Take GUI
>   applications for example. At any time, there should be a unique thread
>   having the GUI context. So, if the GUI thread blocks and doesn't
>   release the context, the remainder function won't get scheduled.

Can anyone please clarify this for me? What exactly is in a context? And how is the context transferred? Which of the above understanding of mine is right or both are wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**
I read [this blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-3-runtime-context) and it has a line `And this extension method demonstrates how to invoke a function with a specified ExecutionContext (typically, captured from another thread)`. This is pushing me to believe that my second idea is closer to correctness.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what you have a question on? They are both saying the same thing but in slightly different ways.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between the two. The first description says that the remainder function should always be scheduled on a particular thread (which has the context). The second description says that the context is like a data structure which can be copied onto any thread and the remainder function can then execute in that thread. My question is `Are any of these descriptions correct?` as in close to what actually happens.

Comment: Sure these are correct. When talking about tasks and continuations you may look at [SynchronizationContext](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,8b34a86241c7b423). If you go through the way from `Task.Run`, you will eventually end up in a method where this SynchronizationContext instance is executed.

Comment: Info regarding ConfigureAwait() method discussed in [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) might be further helpful to clarify the context-related issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each context is different. But in general, they're not *copied*. Contexts are used to *schedule* `Tasks`. That is, to find a suitable thread **and** other resources, as required, and to then execute the task.

In some contexts (GUI), the most important thing is the thread. There's one UI thread, so any `Task` that a GUI context is asked to schedule has to arrange for the UI thread to execute that `Task`.

In some contexts (ASP.Net before core), what's important are the "ambient" request/response/session objects. Those objects should only be accessed by a single thread at a time, but *any* thread can be used. So the context can use thread pool threads but needs to ensure it only executes a single `Task` at a time.

And in the default context, there's no special thread nor any other special resources. Like the ASP.Net context above, any thread pool thread can be used to execute the `Task` but it can schedule `Task`s as quickly as the thread pool will take them.

Comment: I did a bit more reading and I think your answer makes sense to me now. If we forget for a moment that `SynchronizationContext` is a part of `ExecutionContext`, am I correct in saying that context like a specific thread being needed, or only one thread able to access ambient object is actually `SynchronizationContext`. Whereas all the temporary variables that I created in a function which needs to be passed to the remainder function as it may be scheduled on some other thread form a part of the `ExecutionContext`.